# How to sub-module a directory when there is no network?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am managing my code on a server. Although he can't connect to github, it doesn't affect my operation, because I generally don't need remote backup.

I am using a docker image to generate a running environment. I mapped one of my directories inside docker. I now want to better manage this directory. Therefore I want to turn several subdirectories into submodules. This way I can better observe what I have modified.

It's easy if I can connect to github. I can first pass the subdirectory to github and then execute git submodule. But now there is no way to connect to github, what should I do?

I can also upload the directory to my computer first, generate the submodule, and then send it back to the server. But considering that I might add submodules in the future, is there a better way?

Comment: a comment about the premise "I want to turn several subdirectories into submodules. This way I can better observe what I have modified." : you know you can provide a path to `git diff` right ? `git diff that/dir` will list the changes that happened inside that directory only.

Comment: Yes, but I have a lot of modules. Because the experiments I do are CPU-related, sometimes I need some modules to be moved to other servers, so it's easier to manage them with submodules. I find it difficult to make changes and maintain consistency when I make changes on different servers.

Comment: ok. One hacky way to have "all local" is to put all your commits (the ones for your main directory and the ones for your submodules) in your local repo, and just check out the commit you want for each subdirectory. I couldn't get it to work cleanly at the moment -- there are shenanigans with how git creates symlinks when "cloning" a local repository.